# How to filter YTD to last complete month in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am creating a report with buttons that use a slicer to show the last 3 calendar months, the default view, and YTD. The first two are all set and will continue to work fine, however i am having trouble with the YTD filter because i need it to exclude the current month (some of the key metrics for this slicer are only accurate monthly, even thought the data is updated Daily). Any idea how to accomplish this without me having to manually change it every month? An example of it working today would show me 2020 through August, since September is not complete. September would be included in the filter starting October first. I am thankful for your help/insights!

Comment: Need some sample data with your expected output from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically build a calculated column on my date table called something like "Date in Range", that looks something like the below. You could also apply this to a date in a normal table if you are not using a date dimension.

```
Date in Range = IF ('MyTable'[Date] < 
                     DATEADD(TODAY(), -1 * DAY(TODAY()), day), 
                     1, 
                     0)
```

This compares the date in the table row with TODAY(), e.g. 14 Sep 2020, minus the day of the month of today (14), effectively getting you back to the start of the current month. This will then return 1 for dates before the end of last month or 0. Filter on 1 or 0 to get your result (or use something more meaningful in place of the 1 or 0).